# Specify a path other than templates folder for placement of templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I understand that by default the app looks into the template folder of the apps for a specific template name. What happens if I place the templates in a folder called foo ?  How can i tell django to also look under the foo of each folder of every application ?.

Comment: "to look under the foo of each folder", what do you mean by this, look under which folders exactly? In the setting you cal just define all dirs that contain templates.

Comment: @serg I am sorry. I meant to say to look inside the folder `foo` of each application. By default django looks in the template folder of each application instead i would like it to look into a folder called `foo` in each application

Comment: You have multi application and multi template?

Comment: I have multiple applications and each application has two folders which contain html files one folder is called templates and other is called render. How can i tell django to look inside templates and inside the render folder for the prsence of HTML files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add list of directories to `DIRS` in `TEMPLATES` option in django settings

To detect 'foo' template directory under every app, i suggest you to separate the `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple into minimum two different tuples

1. 'PROJECT_APPS' = tuple containing names of your apps
2. 'OTHER_APPS' = tuple of default django apps + third party apps

So `INSTALLED_APPS = PROJECT_APPS + OTHER_APPS`

Now include the template directories to `DIRS` in `TEMPLATES`

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'apps', app_name, 'foo') for app_name in PROJECT_APPS],
    'OPTIONS': {
        'loaders': [
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
        ],
        'context_processors': [
            "django.template.context_processors.debug",
            "django.template.context_processors.media",
            "django.template.context_processors.request",
            "django.template.context_processors.static",
        ]
    }
},
]
```

So now `'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader'` will look into all the directories in `DIRS` and by default the `'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'` loader will look for 'templates' folder in each app.

Ref: [Django loader types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types)

Comment: I havent tested it yet. Will post back once i test it. Thanks for answering

Comment: @JamesFranco Hi did you get a chance to test this ?